# Issue when deploying React app with yarn deploy - semicolon removed by compiler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg

When I run `yarn deploy`, I get this issue. It seems that a semicolon is being removed by the react compiler before the `export default FirebaseContext;` line. What should be done to fix this?

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/firebase/context.js 1:116
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:116)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> import React from"react";var FirebaseContext=React.createContext(null);FirebaseContext.displayName="FirebaseContext"export default FirebaseContext;
```

Note that the original context.js file looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export default FirebaseContext;
```